# Highcharts : How to fix labels to the top when xAxis rotation is 90°?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is the test :

```
$(function() {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Long xAxis legends',
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['a long category name', 'another long category name', 'a very long category name', 'Thats enormous', 'short', 'a long category name', 'another long category name', 'a very long category name', 'Thats enormous', 'short'],
            labels:{
               rotation:90,
               y:100,
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
            name: 'Some values',
            data: [10, 20, 53, 2.51, 1.35, 10, 20, 53, 2.51, 1.35],
            },
            {
            name: 'Other values',
            data: [22.40, 0.15, 40, 10.73, 13, 22, 15, 40.11, 10, 13],
            }
        ],
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'top',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 50,
            y: 65,
            borderWidth: 0,
            margin: 30
        },
    });
});
```

});
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Qhm/1/

**I would like to have a chart with vertical xAxis labels with a top alignment.**

In my real case, i would have many more data, so i can't do otherwise than a rotation.

I have tried the xAxis parameters :
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels

I thought the align would do the trick but when i add it to the rotation parameter, the 
chart is broken.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
align: 'top'
```

like this:

```
labels:{
   rotation:90,
   align: 'top'
   //y:100,
},
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5Qhm/2/

Comment: This works great, but in my case, with my data, this doesn't : i have more than 60 labels (>60 products to display as a chart), and when i add that parameter, i have a js error : Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I have same problem with persian language. your solution work currectly. but when I used rotation:0, x labels not in center. how can i do? Can use both 'center' and 'top' ?

Comment: Hi narges, can you share your fiddle?

Comment: Lorenzo, i ask question in this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161456/how-can-set-both-value-top-and-center-to-align-of-xaxis-label-in-highchart. but i didn't get any answer :(.